# While redirecting to other pages, events in Current pages not firing until redirected page loads

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, web

While redirecting to other pages, events in Current pages not firing until redirected page loads. How to handle the events during other page is processing in Asp.Net

Comment: Please, provide sample code and clarify which events you want to handle.

Comment: Kindly provide some sample code what you have tried

Comment: on a button click i generate a report in other tab, until the report loads, the existing events are not firing

Answer (score 1):

by default, thread of current page stops after redirection. you can keep response active with:

```
Response.Redirect("url", false)
```

Comment: on a button click i generate a report in other tab, until the report loads, the existing events are not firing

Comment: so you are opening a new page in a new tab then, not actually redirecting?

Comment: Yes i accept, but while the process is happening in new tab, the existing controls not firing. once the new tab loaded the control which i clicked fires. how to handle this concurrency?